# French spouse visa when full name changed after marriage

Tags: visas, schengen

I am trying to apply for French Schengen spouse visa as my husband is British. I hold valid Indian passport with valid UK visa. My full name was changed after marriage and I got a new passport issued after it. But now my name on marriage certificate and name on new passport does not match. I have my old passport with name matching with marriage certificate with me but TLScontact people refused to accept my application saying name on my current passport is different from marriage certificate even though my old passport copy was submitted to them. Will I face any issues for getting spouse visa? Does Indian embassy write old name on new passport for reference? How do I tackle this problem?

Comment: Are you currently living in the UK with your husband? Are you planning to go to France on a short visit, or to settle there permanently?

Comment: Yes living in UK with husband and going to France with him for short visit of 4 days.

Comment: Hmm, I was going to suggest you should get the UK authorities (who presumably recognizes your marriage) to issue you a _"Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen"_, pursuant to article 10 of the Freedom of Movement Directive, which would give you a right you to visit Schengen visa-free. However, it looks like the UK is not actually in compliance with the directive and refuses to issue those cards when the union citizen in question is an UK citizen. So I've got nothing ...

Comment: Where and how did you change your name?  There has to be some sort of a document confirming the name change - this document should then be submitted along with the marriage certificate and the new passport.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, the UK will honour the directive if the primary (the Brit) has exercised treaty rights. But without treaty rights, no chance.

Comment: @GayotFow: The treaty seems to give the couple clear rights (namely to travel to France together without getting a visa for the non-EEA spouse). The right exists, it's just the UK that refuses to document the _existence_ of the right in the form specified by the directive.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, I agree with you. But they will *IF* the UK  spouse has exercised treaty rights.  Per the McCarthy judgement...  http://www.jcwi.org.uk/2011/05/26/reflections-on-mccarthy

Comment: @HenningMakholm because the husband is British, the directive does not apply, and the wife is not eligible for an article 10 card.  That's not in conflict with the directive because the husband falls under national law, not under the EU directive.  Every country I'm aware of handles it this way.  Is there some language in the directive that suggests otherwise?

Comment: @phoog: The text of the article is: _"The right of residence of family members of a Union citizen who are not nationals of a Member State shall be evidenced by the issuing of a document called ‘Residence card of a family member of a Union citizen’ ..."_ The OP appears to (a) have a right of residence in the UK -- at least I'm assuming she's not staying there illegally -- (b) be a family member of a union citizen, and (c) not herself a national of a member state. Therefore the three conditions for having her rights under the directive evidenced by said document appear to be satisfied.

Comment: The directive may or may not require the UK to give the OP a right of residence there. But once the UK does decide, for whatever reasons they have, to allow the OP to reside there, it seems inescapable to me that the directive entitles her to have that already-made decision evidenced in the format that the other member states will accept under the directive.

Comment: @HenningMakholm but "This Directive shall apply to all Union citizens who move to or reside in a Member State other than that of which they are a national, and to their family members as defined in point 2 of Article 2 who accompany or join them." (Article 3, §1)  This is the part that excludes radha's husband and therefore radha from the benefits outlined by the directive until they cross into France.  I agree that she ought not to have to re-prove her family status to France, but I don't believe the directive requires that.  It should perhaps be amended.

Comment: @HenningMakholm of course, the staunchest opponent of such an amendment would likely be the UK, since it would increase yet further the number of non-EU family members of EU citizens they would have to admit without requiring an EEA family permit.  But in a month or so that may all be on the way out the door, if the UK decides to leave the EU.

Comment: @phoog: In this situation it seems clear to me that the OP's husband intends to move to France (where "move to", by context and by comparison with other official languages, must mean "travel to" rather than "move house") and therefore the directive applies to him. Indeed, the very act of applying for a Directive 10 card is evidence that the union citizen in question has such an intention, because otherwise the card would not be of any use for the spouse -- remember that she _already has_ some kind of right of residence in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

TLSContact was wrong.  If what they told you was correct, then people who get married in the UK and change their name would be immobile for lack of an identity.

This is a common issue and to handle it, the person submits...

1. The original passport showing the maiden name;
2. The marriage certificate showing the maiden name and the spouse's name
3. The current passport showing the new name.

If TLScontact did not follow this convention, you can still apply either directly or through another agent.

If your husband has exercised treaty rights in the past, you can benefit from the EEA family route and get a residence card.  Otherwise you will need to use the Schengen route.

Comment: Hi Gayot thanks for your reply. In my case I submitted exactly the 3 docs you mentioned above but TLS refused to accept my application, so I booked a direct appointment with french embassy and there they again refused to accept it and asked me to get my maiden name written on my new passport as an observation by Indian embassy. I somehow convinced my embassy do that and also got a marriage certificate from embassy but they still did not accept my spouse visa application stating me that my marriage certificate is not appofilated which means it does not have stamp from Ministry of Foreign affair

Comment: So now I need to go to India and get a stamp from Ministry of foreign affairs to be able to apply for spouse visa. This has been the worst experience of my life so far. The requirement of documents does not make any sense. If UK can grant me a visa then what is problem for French consulate. Why demand such unnecessary documents even though my husband holds a British passport. We also submitted a grievance against the embassy but they did not respond to it and made me apply for a tourist visa even though I am a legitimate spouse. Can I take this matter to a next level?

Comment: @radha, I'm sorry they have put you through this ordeal. It is captious to the extreme and such procedures that you have described simply do not exist. Unfortunately, the EEA does not consider tourism to be a human right and this leaves only the option to complain.  Alternatively, you can try a different Schengen member.  It's sad that this sort of behaviour exists, but there's barely naught to be done about it.